# How to merge two tar gz BinaryIO in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tarfile

I have two Binary I/O stream (both inherit of [BufferedIOBase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase)), which represent two tar archives compressed with gzip algorithm.

Is there any effecient way to create a third one which is the combination of the two others ?

I tried by converting both stream to [`tarfile.Tarfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile) through the `fileobj` arguments and adding each member to a third one :

```py
def merge_environment(a: Optional[BinaryIO], b: Optional[BinaryIO]) -> Optional[BinaryIO]:
    """Merge <a> and <b>, returning a new tarfile.TarFile object.

    If two files in <a> and <b> have the same name, the one in <a> prevails."""
    destio = io.BytesIO()

    with tarfile.open(fileobj=a, mode="r:gz") as t1, \
            tarfile.open(fileobj=b, mode="r:gz") as t2, \
            tarfile.open(fileobj=destio, mode="w:gz") as dest:

        t1_members = [m for m in t1.getmembers() if m.name != ""]
        t1_names = [m.name for m in t1.members]
        t2_members = [m for m in t1.getmembers() if m.name != "" and m.name not in t1_names]

        for member in t1_members:
            dest.addfile(member, t1.extractfile(member))
        for member in t2_members:
            dest.addfile(member, t2.extractfile(member))

    destio.seek(0, 0)
    return destio
```

But this doesn't work if any of the *tar.gz* contain directory since `tarfile.extractfile()` does not work on directory.

Any solution ?

Comment: Did you check this answer https://superuser.com/questions/1122438/optimal-way-to-combine-tar-gz-files-quickly?

Comment: @SebastianKreft Concatening them actually does work, but the resulting archive is bigger than needed (files with the same name are duplicated instead of overwriten).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple, `fileobj` argument of `tarfile.addfile` is not mandatory, `tarinfo` is enough :

```py
destio = io.bytesIO()
with tarfile.open(fileobj=a, mode="r:gz") as t1, \
        tarfile.open(fileobj=b, mode="r:gz") as t2, \
        tarfile.open(fileobj=destio, mode="w:gz") as dest:

    t1_members = [m for m in t1.getmembers()]
    t1_names = t1.getnames()
    t2_members = [m for m in t2.getmembers() if m.name not in t1_names]

    for member in t1_members:
        if member.isdir():
            dest.addfile(member)
        else:
            dest.addfile(member, t1.extractfile(member))

    for member in t2_members:
        if member.isdir():
            dest.addfile(member)
        else:
            dest.addfile(member, t2.extractfile(member))
```